# 1960s (or earlier) movie with a fog blistering people's skin

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember watching the end of this as a child probably before 1970 on TV, only remember it a bit.  People walking out of a fog/mist/smoke from a small town all covered with bumps and blisters.  I don't know if it was B/W or Color, because back then the TV would have been B/W anyway.

Comment: This plot reminds me a bit of the events in the second book of the Hunger Games.

Comment: It definitely sounds like a Hitchcock or Twilight Zone episode with the eerie scene you describe.

Answer (score 14):

Possibly "A Feasibility Study", *Outer Limits* (original series) season 1, episode 29 (1964), in which an entire neighborhood is abducted unawares and placed on a mist-shrouded planet. Humans who contact the aliens become covered with hard blister-like concretions. Plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Feasibility_Study):

> The inhabitants of a six-block suburban area are abducted one night by
> an alien probe, using a means of teleportation to transport the entire
> neighborhood to another planet, Luminos. The intention of the
> Luminoids is to study the feasibility of enslaving the human race for
> manual labor on their planet, since Luminoids themselves suffer from a
> genetic disease which condemns them to become as immobile as rocks as
> they age. Initially, the humans are not aware they've been kidnapped,
> as the neighborhood appears normal. But a thick fog blankets the area,
> and the sun doesn't rise when it should.
>
> Eventually, one of the group is introduced to the Luminoid rulers, who
> are a hideous sight to behold. They make clear what their plans are
> and the punishment for disobedience, which is to be touched and
> contract the terrible disease.
>
> The abductees now realize they're trapped with no chance of ever
> returning home. They come to accept the fact that their lives are
> over. Full submission to the Luminoids cannot protect them from
> inadvertent infection. All that's left is defiance and the will to
> protect the rest of humanity. Forming a circle, they willfully
> contract the disease from one of their own party, making clear that
> mankind will choose death over slavery on Luminos.

Comment: i will call that a definite maybe for sure!  Thanks,  I'll look into it.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not hard to find online. If this is the correct answer, please click on the checkmark to the left to indicate that.

Comment: I just watched that episode, very interesting, but I don't believe that was it.  Their appearance isn't what I remembered, more of overall bumps, not splotchy rocky like that.  And I remember people walking out of the fog covered in them.   The timing of that show is about right, but I don't think it was that.

Comment: Another beautiful hypothesis struck down by an ugly fact! Oh well. It will be interesting to find out the real answer.

Comment: Don't rule out the fact that this was probably from the memory of a 7 year old from 50 years ago, from a snipped of the show that I seem to recall.  I would give that at least a ¼ chance of it being what influenced my faint memories.

Comment: That episode was also [remade in the late 90s](https://theouterlimits.fandom.com/wiki/Feasibility_Study), but obviously it is not what the OP remembers.